# Fotorama - deep linking and browser history

Tags: fotorama

I love the fact that Fotorama updates the URL with a hash specific to each slide, but when I use the browser back button the slideshow doesn't update to the previously viewed slide.
Is there a way to have Fotorama record the deep linking in the browser history, so that using the browsers back/forward buttons update the slide show accordingly?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do that. Write your own solution, using `'fotorama:show'` event and `fotorama.show()`method:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    window.onpopstate = function (e) {
      var hash = location.hash.replace(/^#/, '');
      if (fotorama && hash) {
        fotorama.show(hash);
      }
    };

    var fotorama = $('.fotorama')
        .on('fotorama:show', function (e, fotorama) {
          var hash = fotorama.activeFrame.id || fotorama.activeIndex;
          console.log('fotorama:show', hash);
          if (window.history && location.hash.replace(/^#/, '') != hash) {
            history.pushState(null, null, '#' + hash);
          }
        })
        .fotorama({
          startindex: location.hash.replace(/^#/, '')
        })
        .data('fotorama');
  });
</script>

<!-- Fotorama -->
<div class="fotorama"
     data-auto="false">
  <a href="1.jpg"></a>
  <a href="2.jpg"></a>
  <a href="3.jpg" id="three"></a>
</div>
```

Attribute `data-auto="false"` is important!

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/artpolikarpov/2Enwa/show/

Original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/artpolikarpov/2Enwa/ (not working because of iframe)

Comment: Hi Art, thank you so much!! This is exactly what I needed. I really, really appreciate it!!! Can you please tell me when the API docs will be available for this awesome slideshow?